# Facing a problem analyzing this code segment to find BigO

Tags: java, big-o

```
for (int i = 1; i <= Math.pow(2, n); i = i * 2) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= Math.log(i); j++) {
        sum = i + j;
        System.out.println(sum); // we would like to print the sum..
    }
}
```

How can i count the number of primitive operation my code has?

Comment: Is this your homework? What is your attempt at determining the complexcity yourself?

Comment: Not it's not a homeWork it's in one of the book's problem set but i'm just doing it so i can understand better and face different problems ..

Comment: Ask yourself: How many times does outer loop iterate? How many times does inner loop iterate (worst case)? Multiply the two.

Comment: i deduced that the first line is n + 2

Comment: @CreativeSelf That is still considered "homework", just self-assigned.

Comment: @Andreas You've gone too far with meta-thinking. xD

Comment: i could not figure out the inner loop since it depends on the outer loop

Comment: @CreativeSelf Worst case: `i = pow(2, n)`, and inner loop will iterate `log(i)` times, soo........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analyzing the first loop, you can see that the limit is *2^n* but you can see that the increment step is *i = i x 2*, so how many multiplications until you reach the limit? The answer is obviously *n*.

The inner loop, in the worst case how many iterations will perform? Since it depends on the maximum value that the first loop variable (*i*) will ever take, then it is the natural logarithm of that value, in other words, *log(2^n)*.

Summarizing, the total complexity of the algorithm is `O(n * log(2^n))` which simplifies to `O(n*n)` by taking out the exponent (as promptly suggested by @Andreas).

Comment: [log(2^n) = n * log(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Product,_quotient,_power,_and_root), and constants don't apply, so `n`, i.e. **O(n^2)**

Comment: Regarding the first line we in our Uni we count the last step where we exit the loop so it will become n + 2 , and the log is to the best 2 right? so it become O(n^2) ? but i'm couting the primitive opertions

Comment: @CreativeSelf Constant adders/multipliers are eliminated in Big-O notation.

Comment: @CreativeSelf Big O is order of growth, which is different from counting the number of actual operations which requires knowing `n`, does it not? In other words, your question is unanswerable as-is.

Comment: is it possible to transform log(2^n) to n*log(2) as log is a natural logarithm and e ~ 2.7?